# Error - System.Invalid_Exception - Unknown Error Cannot Focus Element

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

I get the above error message on running this code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CV_Lib_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Instantiate Firefox Driver
            var driver = new ChromeDriver();

            //Old Code - FirefoxDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.cv-library.co.uk/candidate/login");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.cv-library.co.uk/candidate/login");

            //Wait for web element to become visible
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);

            //Enter User Name - Email Address
            var user = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cand-login-left"));
            user.SendKeys("EMAIL");

            //Enter Password - Account Pasword
            var pass = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cand-login-left"));
            pass.SendKeys("PASSWORD");

            //Click on Login button
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("cand-login-left")).Click();




        }
    }
}
```

My research revealed a few similar questions but they were not exactly helpful:

- [Selenium Cannot locate element](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12310/selenium-cannot-locate-element)
- [getting cannot focus element in chrome and edge using java/selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537344/getting-cannot-focus-element-in-chrome-and-edge-using-java-selenium)

Does anyone know how I can implement the action class ( in the case of my code) using C#?

I strongly believe that that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error basically means that *an element you try to interact with is not interactable* - and, yes, if you look at what element is located by the `cand-login-left` id, you would see that this is a `div` element which cannot be focused to send keys to:

```
<div id="cand-login-left">...</div>
```

Locate `email`, `password` fields and "login" button using appropriate locators:

```
// Enter User Name - Email Address
var user = driver.FindElement(By.Name("email"));
user.SendKeys("YOUR EMAIL HERE");

// Enter Password - Account Password
var pass = driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
pass.SendKeys("YOUR PASSWORD HERE");

// Click on Login button
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[title=Login]")).Click();
```